# Does any body knows if there are a ArcSDM version or port for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3

ArcSDM is a series of python analysis tools for ArcGIS developed by Don Sawatzky, Gary Raines y Graeme Boham-Carter in 2010. At present is maitained by the University of Campinhas, Brazil and Geological Survey of Finland.

ArcSDM or SDM (Spatial Data Modeller) "is a collection of tools for adding categorical maps with interval, ordinal or ratio sacle maps to produce a predictive map of where something of intereset is likely to occur." It includes tools for performing spatial analysis using Weights of Evidence, WofE and Logistic Regression, etc.

The original code can by seen at:

http://www.ige.unicamp.br/sdm/

or

http://newprojects.gtk.fi/mpm/ArcSDM5/

These series of tools are used mainly for geosciences, mining exploration, natural hazards, etc.

Does anybody knows if there are a project or port to QGIS?

Comment: I suppose there is no portation towards QGIS. I had a look to the toolboxes and with some work it will be possible to port the scripts towards QGIS. I did a portation of a geophysical toolbox from ArcGis to QGIS in the past. ArcGis is using a central Class (arcgisscripting) to connect to their API. In general the rest of the code and the structure of the script will be usable. I suppose a good programmer (knowing and having both systems) will need around 2 weeks.

Answer (score 2):

I am developing my own version of SDM now named QGIS-GeoSDM at: https://github.com/gasato/QGIS-SDM#qgis-geosdm